# Heroku Domain - my own domain is added as suffix to end of the heroku domain

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I'm having a weird issue whereby after I added the CNAME record with my domain registrar, and I run the "host" command in terminal, my domain lighttree.co.za, is added as a suffix at the end of the heroku domain, which I know (and according to heroku docs) should not be there.

```
$ host ispprov.lighttree.co.za

ispprov.lighttree.co.za is an alias for classical-apple- 
j39juha3sy7h7wnzhso39572.herokudns.com.lighttree.co.za.
classical-apple-j39juha3sy7h7wnzhso39572.herokudns.com.lighttree.co.za 
has address 197.242.146.244
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way DNS work, the CNAME value will append your domain name by default.
You can resolve this by adding a dot (`.`) at the end of your CNAME value.

In your DNS provider configuration, replace the CNAME value to be:

```
classical-apple-j39juha3sy7h7wnzhso39572.herokudns.com.
```

Don't forget the dot at the end :-)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much Damien.   It worked.  Appreciate your assistance.